# What else did you think it stood for? vs ...it stand for? vs ...it stands for?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, questions, predicate

I'm confused about what tense the verb in the predicate of a question should take.  Which of the following versions of *stand* should be used?

1. What else did you think it **stood** for?
2. What else did you think it **stand** for?
3. What else did you think it **stands** for?

Also just to clarify, *it* here refers to a singular noun (like a sign, a symbol, a statue,  and so on).

Comment: Option 2 is simply ungrammatical, bad English.  The other two options do have subtly different meanings.

Comment: @itsbruce, thanks.  When is option 1 used vs when is option 3 used?

Answer (score 1):

The second is incorrect, in that we don't have *stand* with third-person singular, but *stands*, as per the third.

The other two are likely both correct, depending on what is being talked about.

If you are talking about something that is clearly in the past and no longer applies now, then the first is correct.

If you are talking about something that is clearly in the present, then the third is correct.

However, it's likely that what is true currently is also true at the time of the previous statement being made, and so it's both reasonable to use the present tense to talk of now, and the past tense to talk of a few seconds ago when that statement was made. Therefore a lot of the times when the third is applicable because the fact is true now, the first is also applicable.

Meanwhile, sometimes when the past tense is applicable because we are talking about the past, the present is also applicable, at least in the sense of "stand" as applies to meanings: SQPR stood for "Senatus Populusque Romanus" in ancient times, (what else did you think it stood for?) but even though the time of its official use has past, we can still say it stands for that today (what else did you think it stands for?).

As such, it's often fine to use either, with the choice being a matter of whether you opt to emphasise the past of the fact in question, or its present.

Comment: There is also,  "What else do you think it stands for?"